# Crashing when loading a viewpager into a fragment, only Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview

First off, the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:810)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:789)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:756)
        at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.createCachedBitmapIfNeeded(VectorDrawable.java:713)
        at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.draw(VectorDrawable.java:280)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.draw(LayerDrawable.java:517)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:15463)
        at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:15412)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15222)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:598)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14167)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14162)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
```

This doesn't seem to happen on > 6.0 devices, but I can confirm it crashes on Android 5.1.

Some context: The app has a navigation drawer which loads a fragment into the main view. This fragments contains a `ViewPager`, which it itself contains a fragment for each "page". Inside each of those fragments, I have a basic `CardView` with a map in the center and text around.

The stacktrace does not give any hint as to where to look in my code. What might be causing this?

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: have you found any solution?